# telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PeerIdInvalidError: An invalid Peer was used. Make sure to pass the right peer type (caused by SendMessageRequest)

Tags: python, telethon

I am working on a telethon where I want to send message to the users from their telegram ID. I am sending the message from the bot and not from the client. I am taking users Telegram ID from the data frame (newuser) and sending the welcome message to them. But I am facing PeerIDInvalidError.

```
bot = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

for id in newuser['Telegram ID']:
    print('id:', id)
    await bot.send_message(id, 'hello')
```

Comment: Bots cannot start conversations with random users. The users must talk to the bot first.